# getting letter followed by consecutive digits regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s = 'A1902022 N18-2181 A1234567 1-22-2001 A928882190 '
```

I have the following string `s` and I want to get the letter `A` followed by 7 digits. I have tried the following

```
reg = r'[()\d]{7,}'
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
```

Which gives me

```
['1902022', '1234567', '928882190']
```

I would like the following output

```
['A1902022', 'A1234567']
```

How do I tweak

```
 reg = r'[()\d]{7,}'
```

To get my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match an `A` initially. Because there aren't any parentheses in the string, having `()` in the character set doesn't seem useful - then, just match 7 digits with `\d{7}`, and make sure that another digit doesn't follow:

```
A\d{7}(?!\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/WZiNjk/1

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries at each end of `A` then 7 digits:

```
\bA\d{7}\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/JjvRrqrB8399dl).

The word boundaries stop input such as these matching:

```
BA1234567
A12346778
```